# Redirecting to new address if there's specific get parameter

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect this address

```
https://www.example.com/dire-something/simething-else?source=post_page---------------------------/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/dire-something/simething-else
```

Here is what i came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?source=post_page(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^source=post_page$
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}\? [R,L]
```

Comment: kindly check the permission of .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You can't match query strings within `RewriteRule` directive. Use `RewriteCond` for this purpose:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bsource=post_page
RewriteRule . /$0 [QSD,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^source=post_page([^&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}\? [R,L]